# Can I download a list of the bundle IDs I have registered on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I manage my company's Google Play developer account. I need to create a list of the bundle IDs we have registered. iTunes Connect allows me to download a "catalog report" that includes the bundle IDs of all of our iOS apps. Is there a way to do this on google play? I have looked all over and have not found any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Developer Console let's you download several reports: [check list here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/3450942?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986).

See if the subset of one of these gives you a list of package names. You can just select the column and remove duplicates in excel in one click.